# in cocos2d-iphone landscape mode, when admob is added, the first view position is wrong

Tags: ios6, cocos2d-iphone, admob

It is a cocos2d-iphone project with landscape mode.

When there is no admob, the views are ok. But when admob is added,
 all the positions on the first view are wrong which were all moved to the right-down side. When I rotate the screen, everything goes right, all in right position.

I found that with admob, the first view showed is not landscape but portrait.